# How can I deploy everything in one go from dev sandbox to full copy sandbox

Tags: deployment

I have done quite a bit of development in my dev sandbox and want to now deploy it to a full copy sandbox. Is it possible to deploy everything in one go without having to create change sets for every little thing?

Tia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ANT-based [Force.com Migration Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) is suitable for this if you comfortable using Java and the command line or terminal.

There are third party tools for doing this which you can find through Google. Full disclosure that I work for https://gearset.com, a new service that makes this simple and does advanced deployments with things like Profiles and PermissionSets.

Any feedback welcome!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to deploy all your changes from Developer sandbox to a full sandbox in one go. You can use Eclipse IDE/ Force.com Migration tool to move all your changes. You can only move 10,000 components at once which is a limit in salesforce.

Few consideration you need to take while deployment:
1.) Dependencies: The deployment might sometimes fail checking for dependency though you have those components as part of the package.So you need to do them as part of your Post-Deployment steps.

2.)Not All components/ Setup can be deployed via Metadata API in salesforce, so you will have to setup/configure them manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with ANT based deployment tools, easiest way would be to use force.com migration tool. It is easy to use.

While using force.com migration tool, time consuming step is the generation of package.xml, it will take some time to add all components you need to deploy to this file. But now there are scripts out there which will help in generating the package.xml based on the files in your folders. So I think you can follow below steps,

1) pull down all metadata from DEV(Use eclipse/mavensmate)
2) run script and generate package.xml
3) run proper deploy command in your terminal

Comment: can you please let me know which scripts help in generating package.xml